# Get WPF window from Windows Forms control in WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, gdi, windowsformshost

I have a Windows Forms control that is hosted in a WindowsFormsHost.  This is the XAML I use to accomplish this:

```
<Window x:Class="Forms.Address.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Forms.Address"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="New Window" Height="500" Width="720">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host">
            <local:MyFormsControl x:Name="genericName"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to listen to events from the window that the WindowsFormsHost is in.  This is simple in a Windows form because I can use the `FindForm` method to get the form that my control is in.  However, for obvious reasons, `FindForm` does not work when a control is inside of a WindowsFormsHost.  The parent of my control is a `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WinFormsAdapter` and its parent is null.

My question is this: how can find the window that contains my control?

Comment: Would `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle` perhaps help? (You have named your window class "MainWindow", but i am not entirely sure whether it would be really the application's main window...) Note that by getting the native window handle, you can only listen to native Windows event messages, not WPF-specific events...

Comment: No, that was a misnomer; it is not the main window.  Good thinking though.  I'll change the question to remove that detail.

Comment: Darn, you really make it complicated ;-) Right now i can spontaneously only think about three other possibilities. (1) do `new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow).Handle` at an appropriate place and pass the obtained handle somehow to your WinForms control. (2) WinFormsAdapter seems to be an internal/undocumented class. But perhaps it has some field containing the window handle (or other useful data) you could extract through reflection. (3) Use WinAPI `EnumChildWindows` to enumerate all window handles of your process and figure out a way to identify the window handle you are after...

Comment: I would favour either approach (1) or (3) (if they would be feasible). Approach (2) using reflection is somewhat brittle. Fields/methods of such classes which are not part of the framework library could change in unforeseen ways due to framework updates later down the line, potentially breaking functionality of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thanks to elgonzo who suggested I use reflection to get at a field from the WinFormsAdapter class.  Here is how I found the Window:

```
public static Window findParentWindow(Control control) {
    WindowsFormsHost host = findWPFHost(control);
    return Window.GetWindow(host);
}//FindParentWindow

private static WindowsFormsHost findWPFHost(Control control) {
    if (control.Parent != null)
        return findWPFHost(control.Parent);
    else {
        string typeName = "System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WinFormsAdapter";
        if (control.GetType().FullName == typeName) {
            Assembly adapterAssembly = control.GetType().Assembly;
            Type winFormsAdapterType = adapterAssembly.GetType(typeName);
            return (WindowsFormsHost)winFormsAdapterType.InvokeMember("_host", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance, null, control, new string[0], null);

        } else
            throw new Exception("The top parent of a control within a host should be a System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WinFormsAdapter, but that is not what was found.  Someone should propably check this out.");
    }//if
}//FindWPFHost
```

What I did was to first recursively find the WinFormsAdapter, then use reflection to extract the `_host` field from it.  This is the WPF WindowsFormsHost object, so its window can be found using `Window.GetWindow(host)`.

One caveat is that if the WindowsFormsHost is placed in a Windows Form using a ElementHost, `GetWindow` will return null as there is no Window.

Comment: The return line in findWPFHost should be:
return (WindowsFormsHost)winFormsAdapterType.GetField("_host", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(control);

Answer (score 0):

Just add properties to the window(s) and question, and pass the other window on in code. This sounds low-tech and you have to be able to live with the compromises. Not sure how to do this with 100% Xaml.

If you don't like this, compare it to the palatability of other options (winapi, etc). It can be your call!